# How can i solve these Coupled differential Equations?

Tags: ode

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am trying to solve this with
odeint module. But the first equation is function of second equation. If i ignore dw/dz in first equation and second equation is function of first one. I can solve it simply using odeint.
I can solve these equation through fsolve through forward differential. But is it possible i can use Odeint with fsolve? and solve first two equation simultaneously to find.

Comment: As it is right now, your question is not clear enough and it looks like you want that somebody else solve your problem for you. I suggest that you edit your question adding what specific problem are you having with the solution in Python.

Comment: If your question is about how to solve these problems in Python, the answer is by using a numerical solver. You could take a look at SciPy's [integrator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp).

Comment: I am trying to solve this with odeint module. But the first equation is function of second equation. If i ignore dw/dz in first equation and second equation is function of first one. I can solve it simply using odeint. I can solve these equation through fsolve through forward differential. But is it possible i can use Odeint with fsolve? and solve first two equation simultaneously to find.

Comment: The way the equations are normally presented are with the derivative in the left hand side. Did you try solving for the 3 derivatives to rearrange your system?

Comment: I assume this is an initial value problem since you are trying to use odeint? What are the initial conditions?

Comment: Must you use Odeint? A scan through the documentation seems to indicate it doesn't support implicitly-defined ODEs. A python wrapper for SUNDIALS IDA might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would simply replace $\dfrac{d\omega}{dz}$ in the first equation by its expression as given in the second equation, and then regroup on the left-hand side all the terms involving $\dfrac{dT_a}{dz}$.

Then, knowing the values of your overall state vector $X=(T_a,\omega,T_s)$, you have an explicit formulation of $\dfrac{dX}{dz}$.

If this manipulation is not possible by hand, then you may need to use implicit solvers that can handle such a case (see the comment by Steven Roberts for instance), but I don't know much about these.